Using 2 onkeypress-es (with a thread/process) in Python Turtle
Basically, I'm recreating the game Pong in Turtle. I'm aware there's 1000 better languages, modules (I think it's called interfaces), basically ways to do it but I wanted to take on this challenge.
The first problem I got is that when 1 stick moves up or down, the second can't and vice versa.
My first thought was to fix it with a thread/process, however since I am pretty new to programming altogether I couldn't do it.
import turtle
from multiprocessing import Process
ekran = turtle.Screen()
ekran2 = turtle.Screen()
def go_up1():
    if palica1.ycor() <= 525 / 3 -5:
        palica1.goto(palica1.xcor(), palica1.ycor() + 5)


def go_down1():
    if palica1.ycor() >= -525 / 3 + 5:
        palica1.goto(palica1.xcor(), palica1.ycor() - 5)
        

def go_up2():
    if palica2.ycor() <= 525 / 3 + -4:
        palica2.goto(palica2.xcor(), palica2.ycor() + 5)
        


def go_down2():
    if palica2.ycor() >= -525 / 3 + 4:
        palica2.goto(palica2.xcor(), palica2.ycor() - 5)

        
def prva():
    ekran.onkeypress(go_up1, "w")
    ekran.onkeypress(go_down1, "s")
    ekran.listen()

    
def druga():
    ekran2.onkeypress(go_up2, "o")
    ekran2.onkeypress(go_down2,"l")
    ekran2.listen()

    
palica1 = turtle.Turtle()
palica2 = turtle.Turtle()
a = Process(target = prva)
b = Process(target = druga)
a.start()
b.start()
turtle.mainloop()
#this code is partially in my language so don't mind the weird names

I tried the same thing using threads instead of processes and got a not working result but at least there wasn't any errors lol.
p.s. this is a very shortened and simplified version of everything I did already
Thanks for reading!

Does this answer your question? How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics?

@ggorlen hmm well I didn't look at it that way, I guess that might work.... Thanks, I'll try and let you know

Avoid threading, much too complex and tricky to manage. I'd disable tracer and use update()/ontimer to run a loop. Then, when a key is pressed, it should not do anything except essentially flip boolean flags, keeping track of which keys were pressed for the update loop to process on the next frame. Don't do movement directly from handlers. See this for example.

I tried the method from the question you sent, it didn't work... I would show you the code but it's too long.

It works--you'll just need to adapt the technique a bit. Start by running the code in that answer, then try controlling two different turtles with the w/s and up/down keys. Then apply that working example to your main codebase.

@ggorlen I keep rereviewing that post but I don't seem to understand how that helps me move 2 turtles simultaneously with different binds. Looks like this might be too much for me right now, I'll look into it though, atleast I got something now. Thanks a lot!

There's a fundamental flaw to your setup, which is that turtle is handling the event loop, moving everything synchronously with a delay. This means there's no obvious way to bind several key presses such that they fire simultaneously. Instead, disable turtle's event loop and take control of when frames display, so you can reposition turtles arbitrarily. I'd avoid threading entirely in turtle in favor of ontimer, tracer(0) and update().
This answer shows the basic approach for setting up handlers, disabling tracer and using ontimer and update. Read it to understand the fundamental setup for the code below. The only changes here are directing the key handlers to control two turtles instead of one, and making those turtles look and behave like pong paddles.
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.t = t = Turtle()
        t.shape("square")
        t.shapesize(1, 4)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x, 0)
        t.left(90)

    def up(self):
        self.t.forward(step_speed)

    def down(self):
        self.t.backward(step_speed)
        

def tick():
    for action in keys_pressed:
        actions[action]()

    win.update()
    win.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)


win = Screen()
win.tracer(0)
frame_delay_ms = 1000 // 30
step_speed = 10
right_paddle = Paddle(200)
left_paddle = Paddle(-200)

actions = dict(
    Up=right_paddle.up,
    Down=right_paddle.down,
    w=left_paddle.up,
    s=left_paddle.down,
)
keys_pressed = set()

def bind(key):
    win.onkeypress(lambda: keys_pressed.add(key), key)
    win.onkeyrelease(lambda: keys_pressed.remove(key), key)

for key in actions:
    bind(key)

win.listen()
tick()
win.exitonclick()


This honestly looks like black magic to me... I'm speechless.

Less black magic than threading ;-). What about it don't you understand?

well I've never seen any of the functions you are using, I don't understand the tick() and .tracer, and also ever since I've started I never really understood list functions so actions[action]() is really weird to me and I don't understand it. Also I don't understand the need for frame_delay_ms and don't understand what update() does.... However I managed to make it work and even made it so paddles can't go out of borders so I'm happy :).

actions is a dictionary of functions mapping key names to the thing they trigger. So for action in keys_pressed: actions[action]()  loops over all of the pressed keys and invokes the corresponding function associated with the key. frame_delay_ms is the clock speed of the rendering loop that's controlled by ontimer. tracer(0) disables turtle's internal loop and lets you trigger updates with update(), which renders a frame. The docs can help explain these functions, and maybe also ChatGPT might be useful if you ask it to explain.

Part of the confusion is probably that the turtle API has tons of confusingly-named functions. I'm not sure why tracer() was named as it was. Glad you're able to use it--you can treat some of the code as library routines if you want--don't have to understand every detail.
